# Collapsible Accordion in Angular WITHOUT using a JS code, But only HTML. Whenever I click the button, it does nothing. Please solve this

Tags: html, angular, accordion

I am trying to implement an Accordion button on my webpage using the HTML code given below. I am currently implementing this on a very basic scale without using any javascript code with this accordion snippet.
The button just clicks and does nothing and the basic collapsing doesn't take place nor does the accordion functionality is implemented. 
Kindly help me in implementing this!

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
                data toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseButtonExample" aria- 
                expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">Question 
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseButtonExample" >
            <div class="card card-body">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work if there is single element

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="button" #btn (click)="btn.toggle = !btn.toggle"
              >Question 
            </button>
        </div>

        <div  [ngClass]="{collapse:!btn.toggle}" >
            <div class="card card-body">
                <p>1# something</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

if you have many element this trick will work

```
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="button" #btn (click)="btn.toggle = !btn.toggle"
              >Question 
            </button>
        </div>

        <div  [ngClass]="{collapse:!btn.toggle}" >
            <div class="card card-body">
                <p>{{i}}# something</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hxc1v)